# cannot resolve method show(android.support.v4.app FragmentManager,java.lang.string)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

```js
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * Created by jamie on 9/12/2015.
 */
public class PlayersFragment extends DialogFragment {

    ListView lv;
    String[] players = {"arteta", "costa", "reid", "degea", "rooney", "terry"};

    int[] images = {R.drawable.arteta, R.drawable.costa, R.drawable.reid, R.drawable.degea,
            R.drawable.rooney, R.drawable.terry};

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, container, false);

        //initialize listview
        lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        //set dialog title
        getDialog().setTitle("Soccer SuperStars");

        //create adapter obj and set list view to it
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), players, images);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int pos, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), players[pos], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        return rootView;


    }



}
```

Trying to create a `ListView` fragment in android studio and getting 
error

> cannot resolve method show(android.support.v4.app
>   FragmentManager,java.lang.string)

the error is on the `p.show(fm,"Players Fragment)` underlined in red, tried to resolve this but getting nowhere, i would really appreciate a solution to this! thank you

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;




public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    Button showBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         final FragmentManager fm =getSupportFragmentManager();
         final PlayersFragment p=new PlayersFragment();

        showBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        showBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                p.show(fm,"Players Fragment");   //error is here
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: is `PlayersFragment` a subclass of `DialogFragment`?

Comment: add `PlayersFragment` code

Comment: hi, yes PlayersFragment is a subclass of DialogFragment

Comment: i have added the PlayersFragment class above

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suppose you are using `android.app.DialogFragment` and not `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`. Just extend `PlayersFragment` from support library's `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`. Or, if you are not targeting old devices, you can change `getSupportFragmentManager()` to `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: i did try and change getSupportFragmentManager to getFragmentManager but that throws an error too

Comment: i extended PlayersFragment to class to android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment like you said Semyon Danilov and this has solved my problem thank you very much

Comment: @james glad I could help:)

Comment: ugh, thanks, android development seems to be a total circus of issues like this

Comment: Thank You Bossss   You save my time too much

Answer (score 1):

You have to import `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment` on the class `PlayersFragment` and then change `getSupportFragmentManager()` to `getFragmentManager()`.